# How can this code be factored out to reduce duplication (and should it)?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I'm making a basic browser-based game in javascript. This is my control method for the playable character:

```
obj.update = function(){
        if (this.keyPressed === 'right'){
            this.x += 100;
        }
        if (this.keyPressed === 'left'){
            this.x += -100;
        }
        if (this.keyPressed === 'up'){
            this.y -= 100;
        }
        if (this.keyPressed === 'down'){
            this.y -= -100;
        }
        // reset key press
        this.keyPressed = null;
    };
```

I'm conscious that I'm repeating code here. Should I be factoring the repeated elements out? And if so what is the best way to do that?

Comment: Unrelated, but maybe adding 100 to y on down would be clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Should* is a matter of opinion. Answering the *can* part, I'd probably use a `switch`:

```
obj.update = function(){
    switch (this.keyPressed) {
        case 'right':
            this.x += 100;
            break;
        case 'left':
            this.x += -100;
            break;
        case 'up':
            this.y -= 100;
            break;
        case 'down':
            this.y -= -100;
            break;
    }
    // reset key press
    this.keyPressed = null;
};
```

...and probably make `100` a constant (in ES2015/ES6) or a variable I didn't change (in ES5 and earlier).

Although it's also tempting to use an object (or in ES2015/ES6 a `Map`) as a lookup table:

```
var table = {
    right: {x:  100, y:    0},
    left:  {x: -100, y:    0},
    up:    {x:    0, y: -100},
    down:  {x:    0, y:  100}
};
obj.update = function(){
    var entry = table[this.keyPressed];
    if (entry) {
        this.x += entry.x;
        this.y += entry.y;
    }
    // reset key press
    this.keyPressed = null;
};
```

Comment: I like the second part. The first part is not so much factoring out repeated elements, but I can see that a switch is cleaner.

Comment: @DizzyEgg: Yeah, the `switch` basically just factors out where the value is coming from, which doesn't buy us much here.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably make this more readable with a [`switch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzc6t81t(v=vs.94).aspx) statement:

```
switch (this.keyPressed) {
    case 'right': this.x += 100;  break;
    case 'left' : this.x += -100; break;
    case 'up'   : this.y -= 100;  break;
    case 'down' : this.y -= -100; break;
}
this.keyPressed = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make an object and call it with `this`.

The smart part of this solution, it is open for some more commands, like saving a state, or other.

```
var op = {
    right: function (t) { t.x += 100; },
    left: function (t) { t.x -= 100; },
    up: function (t) { t.y -= 100; },
    down: function (t) { t.y += 100; }
};

obj.update = function () {
    var f = op[this.keyPressed];
    f && f(this);
    this.keyPressed = null;
};
```